# Windows was unable to complete the format

Tags: ntfs, format, fat32

Hi all I trying to format the memory card of mine but windows can't able to format it.

I have tried for hours finding the solutions on the net but got nothing so far. Is there any way I can format my card.

my sdcard is of 2gb but when i format the card it shows the capacity of the drive only of 30.6 mb.

I have tried solution provided here

http://www.superpctricks.com/2013/10/windows-was-unable-to-complete-format.html

and also here

http://servercomputing.blogspot.in/2012/08/Windows-was-unable-to-complete-the-format.html

both with Fat32 and Ntfs

with Fat32 it shows

```
the type of file system is raw
the new file system is fat32
quick formatting 30m
the volume is too small for fat32
```

and with ntfs it shows

```
the type of file system is raw
the new file system is ntfs
quick formatting 30m
volume <32 characters, enter for none>?
creating file system structures
the first ntfs boot sector ia unwriteable.
All ntfs boot sector are unwriteable cannot continue
format failed.
```

I also tried many recovery softwares and tools but nothing happened.
So how can I format my card and recover my data.

Answer (score 1):

Trash it, buy a new one.
They are not worth fixing once they start to fail.

I get through literally hundreds of them for work, with 'write few, read many' deploys - fail rates are high.

*Caveat: don't use SD for mission-critical storage.*

Comment: So finally did I lost my data forever.

Comment: If you want to try recover data from it, try Recuva [https://www.piriform.com/recuva] or similar. Don't keep trying to format it, you'll just make it worse... THEN throw the card away.

Comment: sorry bro but the link you gave is not working

Comment: stoopid link thinks the ] is part of it - https://www.piriform.com/recuva

Answer (score 1):

The error "Windows was unable to complete..." or "The drive is write protected..." means the flash drive gets damaged, usually physical damage, such as bad sectors or memory chip problem.
I've searched solutions of this problem for a long time, and I found there are mainly three solutions:

1. Format memory card with Disk Management, which works for few cases.
2. Format with Command Prompt. Users who are not good at computer operations will feel it's difficult to try this solution. Formatting with command line works for many flash drive.
3. The last solution is a third-party tool. You need to find the correct tool to help you.

It's very possible that none of them works and you need to but a new memory card in that case.

Reference: http://www.eassos.com/how-to/windows-was-unable-to-complete-the-format.php

Answer (score 0):

You can recovery the sd card by some recovery software like [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva), but just like the others said, it is not worth to fix.